# ASP.NET: How can I explore the default user database

Tags: asp.net, database

So if I create a new MVC project with basic log in template, there should be somewhere a database which contains all the user login information. There's even the default connection string which points to it.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyProjectName-20140521042155.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyProjectName-20140521042155;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

How ever, when exploring the project folder I cannot find it. I also tried to turn on "show all files" option in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Management Studio can be used to connect to the local db server. You can also use visual studio server explorer.